# How can I extract all mails and passwords from my log file?

Tags: linux, bash

I have my log file with the format shown below, and I have my regex to extract all my emails and it works perfectly, but it doesn't show my passwords that are on the second line after email.

```
<tr><th><span>09:52:08 a.m. </span>xxxx@gmail.com</th></tr>
<tr><th><span>09:52:17 a.m. </span>xxxx</th></tr>
```

How can I show it? I tried with a second regex, but it fails. Any tips?

```
 m4st3rrulezs@m4st3rrulezs:~/Downloads/attachments$ ls;cat *.html |  grep --color=always -E -o "\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b" | sort -u
    PC-4-PC_PC-4_2018-10-25.html  PC-4-PC_PC-4_2018-10-28.html  PC-4-PC_PC-4_2018-10-31.html  PC-4-PC_PC-4_2018-11-03.html
    PC-4-PC_PC-4_2018-10-26.html  PC-4-PC_PC-4_2018-10-29.html  PC-4-PC_PC-4_2018-11-01.html  PC-4-PC_PC-4_2018-11-05.html
    PC-4-PC_PC-4_2018-10-27.html  PC-4-PC_PC-4_2018-10-30.html  PC-4-PC_PC-4_2018-11-02.html
    18zxxxxx@gmail.com
```

I don't want to search one by one.

Comment: Looks like you'd better use an xml parser. `xmlstarlet` which is natively installed on many linux distros provide you the ability to select data from XML sheets with XPath and would be much more appropriate than `grep` for this task as far as I can tell.

Comment: If you insist on using `grep` I think you should use a first regex to retrieve the two lines using `-A 1` with your current regex, then a second `grep` to extract what's after `</span>` and before `</th>`. Using `grep -P` and assuming your passwords and emails can't contain the `<` character, `</span>\K[^<]*` would do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
cat *.html | sed 's/.*span>\(.*\)<\/th>.*/\1/'
```

It removes everything and keeps only what is between `<span>` and `</th>`, which in this case is the email and password you want to extract.